# INSERT into statement not working in oracle when using INSERT INTO .. SELECT * FROM

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-insert

I have `vh_emp` table whose table structure is(This is empty table):

[image]

I am taking data from `employee` table as source table where I wrote some query to match with vh_emp table:

```
SELECT e.emp_id       EMP_ID, 
       e.emp_name     EMP_NAME, 
       e.dob          DOB, 
       e.join_date    JOIN_DATE, 
       CASE 
         WHEN e.leave_date IS NULL THEN Trunc(sysdate) 
         ELSE e.leave_date 
       END            AS LEAVE_DATE, 
       e.salary / 100 SALARY, 
       d.dept_name    DEPT_NAME, 
       one.addr_name  ADDRESS_ONE, 
       two.addr_name  ADDRESS_TWO, 
       b.emp_name     AS MANAGER_NAME 
FROM   offc.employee e 
       LEFT JOIN offc.department d 
              ON e.dept_id = d.dept_id 
       LEFT JOIN offc.add_line_one one 
              ON e.line1 = one.addr_id_one 
       LEFT JOIN offc.add_line_two two 
              ON e.line2 = two.addr_id_two 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * 
                        FROM   offc.employee) b 
                    ON e.manager_id = b.emp_id;
```

The query is running fine and the output is coming fine from this query:

[image]

So,I wanted to insert these data in `vh_emp` tables using :

```
INSERT INTO offc.vh_emp 
            (emp_id, 
             emp_name, 
             dob, 
             join_date, 
             leave_date, 
             address_one, 
             address_two, 
             salary, 
             manager_name, 
             dept_name) 
SELECT e.emp_id       EMP_ID, 
       e.emp_name     EMP_NAME, 
       e.dob          DOB, 
       e.join_date    JOIN_DATE, 
       CASE 
         WHEN e.leave_date IS NULL THEN Trunc(sysdate) 
         ELSE e.leave_date 
       END            AS LEAVE_DATE, 
       e.salary / 100 SALARY, 
       d.dept_name    DEPT_NAME, 
       one.addr_name  ADDRESS_ONE, 
       two.addr_name  ADDRESS_TWO, 
       b.emp_name     AS MANAGER_NAME 
FROM   offc.employee e 
       LEFT JOIN offc.department d 
              ON e.dept_id = d.dept_id 
       LEFT JOIN offc.add_line_one one 
              ON e.line1 = one.addr_id_one 
       LEFT JOIN offc.add_line_two two 
              ON e.line2 = two.addr_id_two 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * 
                        FROM   offc.employee) b 
                    ON e.manager_id = b.emp_id;
```

But,I executed this query I got error as:

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

The structure of table `employee` is:
[image]

why is this error coming? I reviewed and saw that datatype is same for the column and value of select statement.This error should not appear as column datatype is matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order of your `insert` clause column name and `select` clause column name should match.

Please match the positions of them as following:

```
INSERT INTO offc.vh_emp 
            (emp_id, 
             emp_name, 
             dob, 
             join_date, 
             leave_date, 
             Salary,  -- this
             dept_name, -- this
             address_one, 
             address_two,
             manager_name 
             ) 
SELECT e.emp_id       EMP_ID, 
       e.emp_name     EMP_NAME, 
       e.dob          DOB, 
       e.join_date    JOIN_DATE, 
       CASE 
         WHEN e.leave_date IS NULL THEN Trunc(sysdate) 
         ELSE e.leave_date 
       END            AS LEAVE_DATE, 
       e.salary / 100 SALARY, 
       d.dept_name    DEPT_NAME, 
       one.addr_name  ADDRESS_ONE, 
       two.addr_name  ADDRESS_TWO, 
       b.emp_name     AS MANAGER_NAME 
FROM   offc.employee e 
       LEFT JOIN offc.department d 
              ON e.dept_id = d.dept_id 
       LEFT JOIN offc.add_line_one one 
              ON e.line1 = one.addr_id_one 
       LEFT JOIN offc.add_line_two two 
              ON e.line2 = two.addr_id_two 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * 
                        FROM   offc.employee) b 
                    ON e.manager_id = b.emp_id;
```

Cheers!!